# QT4 qlistview save icon position moved by hand for the next time

Tags: c++, qt4, qlistview

I'm developing an app with qt4.3 which opens a window with a bunch of icons loaded from .desktop files. It tries to emulate a file browser but without file browsing... I mean, you can double click and open an app or drag the icons to an other position not necessary attached to the grid.

I'm using a qdirmodel and a qlistview in "icon mode".

My problem is that I can't save the position of the icons once I moved them. Every time I restart the app, I get the icons loaded in the default position.
I can't find any way to know the position of an item or move an item to a position.

What I should do? Do I have any chance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the qlistview code I found that I can also inherit the qlistview class and convert to public a couple of protected functions which return the item position and move the item to a position. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure, you can save item's position. You should read about `save session qt`.
This is official qt doc about `Session Management` [Session Management](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/session.html)
And also I'll advice to read qt's possibility save settings [QSettings](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qsettings.html)